# Can not connect Azure Functions to MongoDB (created in azure)

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I have a MongoDB setup on azure, and I am tring to connect to it via azure function.

These are the steps I took:

1. Creating a Simple Azure Function
2. Installed the MongoDB Driver on Azure, To install the MongoDB Node.js driver, I went go to .scm.azurewebsites.net, and clicked on 'Debug Console' -> 'PowerShell'.
3. I Navigated to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory and clicked on the plus icon to create a new file called package.json.
4. I Created and saved the below package.json file.

   ```
     {
     "name": "nameofunction",
     "dependencies": {
      "mongodb": "3.x"
     }
   }
   ```
5. Next, I ran `npm install` from the shell.
6. From the Azure Function I should be able to connect to MongoDB and execute a query using the below code.

   ```
   const  mongodb = require('mongodb');
   const  url = "mongodb://cosmod:  <PASSWORD>==@cosmodb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb";

   module.exports = async function (context, req) {
       mongodb.connect(url, function(error, client) {        
         if (error) throw error;
         var dbo = client.db("mydb");
         dbo.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            context.log("Collection created!");
            db.close();
         });         
      });
    };
   ```

My code is throwing up a `Status: 500 Internal Server Error`

The more I look at the code, the more i can not understand why this should not work. 
The `package-lock.json`has all the dependencies loaded after I ran `npm install` in the shell.

I appreciate any help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems weired, I also followed same and was able to connect to my db.
Can you please check your cosmos connectiondb, mongo compatible connection string? Are you able to connect that from other mongo clients

Answer (score 0):

> Status: 500 Internal Server Error

I assume that it dues to the code  `mongodb.connect(url, function(error, client)`

please change the code to

`mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(error, client)`

Answer (score 0):

A review of the Azure Cosmos DB account- Quick start documentation accessible via the Azure Cosmos DB account menu side blade; connecting the MongoDB app is among others via:

1. the Node.js 2.2 driver and
2. the Node.js 3.0 driver

I was using the Node.js 2.2 driver connection string in the azure function which is not compatible with the Node.js 3+ driver dependency in my app. Using the Node.js 3.0 driver connection string, I was able to connect the MongoDB app, without the error. The double equality sign in the password string is url encoded in the 3+ driver.

`Node.js 3+ driver connection string`

```
 var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
 mongoClient.connect("mongodb://cosmodb:<PWD>%3D%3D@cosmodb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true", function (err, client) {
  client.close();
});
```

`Node.js 2.2 driver connection string`

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://cosmodb:<PWD>==@cosmodb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true", function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```